# Is there a implementaion of the foundation framework for panels?

Tags: panels, theming

I recently heard about the foundation framework and I wondered if there is an implementation for panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ongoing work in the [Zurb Foundation Theme](http://drupal.org/project/zurb-foundation) to [implement Panels support](http://drupal.org/node/1849746).

It look's like there has [been some progress](http://drupal.org/node/1849746#comment-6981580), I'd check that discussion out first and foremost; then have a look at the [search for Panels](http://drupal.org/project/issues/zurb-foundation?text=panels&status=All) in that module. There might be more...